# override admin system account controller in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, admin-controller

click

> System > My Account

When I click on 'save account' button,it will call saveAction() method,saveAction() location is **"Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/AccountController.php"**,I tried to override saveAction() method but i can't, I also delete cache but it doesn't override system accountcontroller,please check my code where is my mistake ?

> app/code/local/Test/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>  
       <Test_Module>  
         <version>0.0.1</version>  
       </Test_Module>  
     </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Test_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Test_Module_Adminhtml</Test_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Test/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/AccountController.php

```
     <?php
  //require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/AccountController.php'; 
 require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Adminhtml_System').DS.'AccountController.php');

    class Test_Module_Adminhtml_AccountController extends Mage_Adminhtml_System_AccountController
    {
        public function saveAction() 
        {
            die('override');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

> app/etc/modules/Test_Module.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Test_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Your `app/code/local/Test/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>  
       <Test_Module>  
         <version>0.0.1</version>  
       </Test_Module>  
     </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <test_module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Test_Module_Adminhtml</test_module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
</config>
```

Your `app/code/local/Test/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/System/AccountController.php`

```
<?php
//require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/AccountController.php';

require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'System'.DS.'AccountController.php');

class Test_Module_Adminhtml_System_AccountController extends Mage_Adminhtml_System_AccountController
{
    public function saveAction() 
    {
        die('override');
    }
}
?>
```

**Remember**

Folder structure should be exactly as core controller is.

Comment: I used your code but Still not working

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think there was problem in config.xml too.

Comment: If still doesn't work, I doubt it's naming problem for your NameSpace and ModuleName. You might want to change `Package1` and `Module1` to something different, without number.

Comment: Still not working,also delete cache folder but why it doesn't work ?

Comment: ok I am updating

Comment: Did you clear the cache from `System > Cache management` section?

Comment: yes I clear cache

Comment: I have updated my code and changed my package and module name

Comment: Is your controller file is inside `Adminhtml` folder? Folder name should start with capital `A`.

Comment: My AccountController.php file location is app/code/local/Test/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/AccountController.php

Comment: please check this all code in your magento instance

Comment: Please apply or check in your magento instance,if it work perfectly in your instance,it means error in my magento instance

Comment: Your controller should be in `local/Test/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/System/AccountController.php`

Comment: wow what a great solution,thanks it works,why we put in system folder ?

Comment: For controller you should follow same folder structure as magento core does.